# Extract/Export existing Google Bigquery project DDL as a SQL file?

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to version control all our existing Google Bigquery code.
Is there a script/program that can extract all the DDL into SQL files foldered by the dataset?

Mostly I'm trying to extract Routines and Views, as the tables are generated by stored procedures

Answer (score 0):

You can view all rountines (udf functions) by:

```
Select * 
from `region-us`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
```

More details can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-routines).

```
Select * 
from `region-us`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS
```

Both results can be saved to a csv-file. The issue with the DDL part is that the quotes will be messed up.